# I downloaded yesterday some updates from software center as usual and both wifi and ethernet do not work anymore

Tags: software-installation, wifi, appcenter, ethernet

[image]

Hi everyone. I have a macbook from 2009, I downloaded and installed updates from the Software Center as usual yesterday night and after the reboot both wifi and ethernet did not work. The network worked just fine before 10pm but not after the reboot. I attach a picture I took to show the last updates installed. I think I must delete some of these updates manually using Synaptic Package Manager, I can find all of them with it, but I would like to know which ones.

Answer (score 1):

Install both linux-firmware and linux-firmware-nonfree packages,e.g.

> sudo apt-get install linux-firmware linux-firmware-nonfree

and reboot.

For me Installing newer drivers solved the problem from this article or you can go through this for your specific need.[My WiFi adapter is not working at all, how to troubleshoot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-how-to-troubleshoot)